# Finitely generated modules over discrete valuation ring.

Tags: commutative-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

I am looking for a reference to the following well known fact:

Any finitely generated torsion free module over a discrete valuation ring is free of finite rank.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A discrete valuation ring is a principal ideal domain and a finitely generated torsion free module over a PID is free of finite rank. This in turn follows from the [structure theorem for modules over a PID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structure_theorem_for_finitely_generated_modules_over_a_principal_ideal_domain).